# Variable available in all controller method? Codeigniter 3

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

In my controller:

```
        class Admin extends CI_Controller
        {

            public function dodaj()
            {
                $data['stanowiska'] = array(
                    'admin' => 'Administrator',
                    'ksiegowy' => 'Księgowy',
                    'glowny_ksiegowy' => 'Główny księgowy'
                );
                $this->load->view('dodaj', $data);
            }

            function edytuj()
            {
                $data['stanowiska'] = array(
                    'admin' => 'Administrator',
                    'ksiegowy' => 'Księgowy',
                    'glowny_ksiegowy' => 'Główny księgowy'
                );

                $this->load->view('edytuj_uzytkownika', $data);
            }
        }
```

Have two variables $data['stanowiska'] and everything works fine but I need only one var like this. When I use this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $data['stanowiska'] = array(
        'admin' => 'Administrator',
        'ksiegowy' => 'Księgowy',
        'glowny_ksiegowy' => 'Główny księgowy'
    );
}
```

I got this message:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: stanowiska

What shoud I do to fix that problem? thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to use property from `__construct()` method in other methods, you have to use `$this` keyword. Proper way would be:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = []; //array initialization

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['stanowiska'] = array(
            'admin' => 'Administrator',
            'ksiegowy' => 'Księgowy',
            'glowny_ksiegowy' => 'Główny księgowy'
         );
    }

    public function dodaj()
    {
        $this->load->view('dodaj', $this->data);// using data array from constructor
    }

    public function edytuj()
    {
        $this->load->view('edytuj_uzytkownika', $this->data);// same here
    }
}
```